# Exception while using spring data commons for Page.map method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-commons

I am getting below exception on executing jar :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>
```

(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V

I have added the following dependency in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with parent as :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine when added dependency after hours of hit and trial :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```